# How to Scope Model Data in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need to save `project_id` in to `task` table according to the relevant projects from using `Project` model.

`Project` Model

```
public function scopeProject($query, $id)
{
    return $query->where('project_id', $id);
}
```

Now I am going to save to task table using store method in TaskController as following

```
public function store(Request $request, $id, Task $task)// this is line 45
{
    $task = new Task;
    $task->task_name   = $request->input('name');
    $task->body = $request->input('body');
    $task->assign          = $request->input('status');
    $task->priority        = $request->input('status');
    $task->duedate  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input("date")));// $request->input('date');
    $task->project_id        = $id;
    $task->save();
}
```

But when I am going to save this data following error is occurred

> ErrorException in TasksController.php line 45:
>        Argument 3 passed to App\Http\Controllers\TasksController::store() must be an instance of App\Task, none given

Then how can I grab `project_id` from using `Project` Model to My `TaskController`?

Comment: What's the route look like. Is it something like this `Route::post('/projects/{project}/tasks', '...');

Comment: My route is Route::resource('tasks','TasksController');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got result in this way.....
TaskController

```
public function postNewTask(Request $request,$id, Project $project)
{

    $task = new Task;
    $task->task_name   = $request->input('name');
    $task->body = $request->input('body');
    $task->assign = $request->input('status');
    $task->priority = $request->input('status');
    $task->duedate  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input("date")));
    $task->project_id = $id;
    $task->save();
```

form url

```
<form  method="post" action="{{ route('projects.tasks.create', $project->id) }}">
```

and routes

```
Route::post('projects/{projects}/tasks', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@postNewTask',
    'as' => 'projects.tasks.create'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `project_id` as a query string or as a hidden input if you are not using [Laravel Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding)

**Example using route model binding**

Define your route like following

```
Route::post('/projects/{project}/tasks', 'TaskController@store');
```

Set the tasks relation in `Project` model

```
public function tasks() {
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Task::class);
}
```

And in your controller

```
public function store(Request $request, Project $project)
{
    $task = new Task;
    $task->task_name   = $request->input('name');
    $task->body = $request->input('body');
    $task->assign = $request->input('status');
    $task->priority = $request->input('status');
    $task->duedate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->input("date"));

    // This will set the project_id on task and save it
    $project->tasks()->save($task);
}
```

**Example using query string or hidden input**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task;
    $task->task_name   = $request->input('name');
    $task->body = $request->input('body');
    $task->assign = $request->input('status');
    $task->priority = $request->input('status');
    $task->duedate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->input("date"));

    // Find the project with the given id
    $project = Project::findOrFail($request->get('project_id'));

    // This will set the project_id on task and save it
    $project->tasks()->save($task);
}
```

Comment: you mean may I need column as project_id in My task table

Comment: Yes. you need a `project_id` in `tasks` table if tasks belongs to a project which I assumed while giving the answer.

Comment: then I need to know that can not i use store method with Route::resource

Comment: You can use nested resources. `Route::resource('projects.tasks', 'TasksController')

Comment: what wrong with Route::resource('tasks','TasksController');

Comment: Nothing wrong there. If you are using that approach you need to pass the `project_id` by passing it on url as a query string in form action or as a hidden input element within your form.

Comment: in your comment "If you are using that approach you need to pass the project_id by passing it on url as a query string in form action" means may I use POST in My route directions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151877/discussion-between-chanafdo-and-lion).